# Calculate $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(G,k^{\times})\otimes\mathbb{Z}/p{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I have a question about Hom and tensor.

Let $G$ be a finte abelian group and let $k$ is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. I want to calculate the following:

$Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(G,k^{\times})\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/p{\mathbb{Z}}$

I tried to solve this problem. Since $G$ is finite abelian, without loss of generality, we assume that $G=\mathbb{Z}/q^n\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime $q$ and some integer $n$. Since $G$ is cyclic, every homomorphism $\phi$ starting $G$ is completely determined by $\phi(1)$. But $1$ has an order $q^n$ in $G$, so $|\phi(1)|$ divides $q^n$.

How to proceed my proof? Or is there a new proof for this problem? I think if we consider this problem with the tensor product, it may be solved easily. Please give me a hint or solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you go from "finite abelian" to "cyclic"?

Comment: We may know the classification for finitely generated abelian groups. (In our case, finite abelian, so it's more easier.) Also, Hom and direct sum commute with each other, so I assume the case.

Comment: first of, grammar it is either "more easy" or "easier", the latter being the most common, no need for double comperative. Secondly, you cannot make such assumption as $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ is abelian and finite but not cyclic.

Comment: He is saying that $Hom_\mathbb{Z}(G,k^\times)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ may be written as a direct sum of the same form where $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: I mean that Hom(Z_2 x Z_2, H) = Hom(Z_2,H) x Hom(Z_2,H)